# How to interpret Wilcoxon rank sum result

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, scipy

I have 2 algorithms, A and B, and 9 data-sets. I ran both algorithms on the data-sets and got 9 pair of results. I have to prove that algorithm A is better than algorithm B by comparing the results. I used Wilcoxon rank sum test to prove it. I used scipy ranksums function. Following is the python code I used:

```
from scipy.stats import ranksums

x = [585292.87, 35861712.63, 19572540.87, 245910755.60, 298607172.50, 1794109580.00, 2042209644.00, 3721912787.00, 3063761003.00]
y = [665323.58, 68278548.03, 27903345.88, 331285811.30, 335398848.10, 2015596867.00, 2488404961.00, 3989410243.00, 3221495744.00]

print(ranksums(x, y))
```

Here, x contains results of algorithm A and y contains results of algorithm B. This produced following result:

```
RanksumsResult(statistic=-0.48566186425718272, pvalue=0.62720692637201214)
```

What is the interpretation of this result? The examples I saw have very low p values ([like this](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~wild/ChanceEnc/Ch10.wilcoxon.pdf)). Why is the p value high in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High p-value means that you didn't find a proof that algorithms A and B differ. This may be caused by many reasons, some of them are:

- small sample (only 9 data sets)
- lack of difference between them (maybe you are trying to show something that is not true)
- unappropriate test used.

In my opinion the last one is the case. I'd suggest paired Wilcoxon test, because results of algorithms A and B come in pairs (pair of results on 1st data set, pair of results on 2nd data set, and so on)

I ran this test in R (sorry, I'm not a Python user) and I got p=0.004.

```
> x = c(585292.87, 35861712.63, 19572540.87, 245910755.60, 298607172.50, 1794109580.00, 2042209644.00, 3721912787.00, 3063761003.00)
> y = c(665323.58, 68278548.03, 27903345.88, 331285811.30, 335398848.10, 2015596867.00, 2488404961.00, 3989410243.00, 3221495744.00)
> 
> wilcox.test(x,y, paired=T)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x and y
V = 0, p-value = 0,003906
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: I just installed R, and indeed this is the result. But is this p value significant enough to say A is better than B? Any guidance will be appreciated :)

Comment: It depends of significance level on which you perform your analysis. Typically significance level is 0.05 and any p-value below this means that algorithms significantly differ. Maybe, you sholud also consider one-sided test if you're only interested in showing that A is better than B.

Comment: Good answer, but I do not like the suggestion for the one-sided test. One sided tests are only appropriate if the other side (here: B being faster than A) is not only improbable, but completely impossible, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Knarpie superiority or non-inferiority tests are usually one-sided. It's not a question about whether the other alternative is unlikely, but that we are not interested in rejecting in favor of the other alternative. That is, we only care about the power for the directional test to reject infavor of superiority..

Comment: @Knarpie I don't see why impossibility must be a requirement; you need only be uninterested in it being in your alternative ... as long as the null is clearly $\leq$ and not merely $=$, so that you don't attempt to treat them as close-to-equal when you fail to reject.